# .htaccess redirect with Chinese characters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect

```
新闻/事件/finance-for-sdgs-high-level-meeting-bellagio-financeforsdgs-2/?lang=zh-hans
```

to

```
/finance-for-sdgs-high-level-meeting-financeforsdgs-bellagio-25-27-february-2015/?lang=zh-hans
```

but am not sure of the encoding. The following is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^æ°é»/äºä»¶/finance-for-sdgs-high-level-meeting-bellagio-financeforsdgs-2/?lang=zh-hans$ http://ecosequestrust.org/finance-for-sdgs-high-level-meeting-financeforsdgs-bellagio-25-27-february-2015/?lang=zh-hans [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the `\x` escape sequence to escape the Unicode:

```
RewriteRule ^\xE6\x96\xB0\xE9\x97\xBB\x2F\xE4\xBA\x8B\xE4\xBB\xB6/finance-for-sdgs-high-level-meeting-bellagio-financeforsdgs-2/$ http://ecosequestrust.org/finance-for-sdgs-high-level-meeting-financeforsdgs-bellagio-25-27-february-2015/ [R=301,L]
```

Essentially, replacing the `新闻/事件` with `\xE6\x96\xB0\xE9\x97\xBB\x2F\xE4\xBA\x8B\xE4\xBB\xB6`. This way, you don't need to rely on the encoding of the htaccess file.

Comment: the encoding seems to work now but only if the query string is removed from the URL, is there a syntax issue with the query string too?

Comment: @AndreHead sorry, I copied and pasted the entire thing. The query string isn't supposed to be part of the rule at all

Comment: thanks, is there no way of including the query string in the rule / logic in some way? it could be useful in some instances

Comment: @AndreHead the query string is appended to the target automatically. If you want to match against the query string, you need to use a `RewriteCond` and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable